# Can hard links get broken?

Tags: git, bash, unix

I have the feeling that from time to time my hard links get broken.

I use to synchronize a couple of copies by creating links via, e.g.:

```
link ~/work/genDocs/bibs/SKM.bib SKM.bib
```

Once a while I recognize that a synchronization hasn't taken place and I "renew" the link. Personally I don't think, this should happen, but may it be that such links get broken?

Reasons I can think of:

- system updates
- interference with version control (I use git)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can happen if the original file (`~/work/genDocs/bibs/SKM.bib`) is recreated instead of being modified in-place. A new inode will be created, but your link will still point to the old inode. You can fix the issue by creating symbolic links with `ln -s` instead of hard links with `link`. See [What is the difference between a symbolic link and a hard link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link)

Comment: +1 For example, `sed -i` creates a new modified file, then replaces the original with it.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid inode changes when modifying the contents of files there is the Unix text file editor `ed`.

Although (almost) all `ed` implementations make use of temporary files as well (see ["In-place" editing of files](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/)), `ed` - unlike `sed -i` (as already pointed out by chepner) - modifies files "in-place" without changing their respective inodes (see [Editing files with the ed text editor from scripts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed)).

```
# sed & ed example to demonstrate whether inode is being changed or preserved

# sed
# inode is changed
{
rm -Pfv testfile.txt
echo a > testfile.txt
ls -i testfile.txt
sed -i -e 's/a/A/' testfile.txt
ls -i testfile.txt
}

# ed
# inode is not changed
{
rm -Pfv testfile.txt
echo a > testfile.txt
ls -i testfile.txt
printf '%s\n' 'H' ',s/a/A/' 'wq' | ed -s testfile.txt
ls -i testfile.txt
}

# > 
# redirection operator preserves inode (on Mac OS X 10.6.8)
{
rm -Pfv testfile.txt
echo a > testfile.txt
ls -i testfile.txt
echo A > testfile.txt
ls -i testfile.txt
}
```