# node -bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux

I am having this error with node. Running Debian 7 (Wheezy) a VPS.

I have this error if I for example run this command (in the directory of the .js)

```
node sell.js
```

or

```
screen node sell.js
```

They both don't work, because I am getting this error:

> -bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Does it get fixed if you say `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`? (from a [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911#issuecomment-18951288))

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: @Epodax I am sorry wrong tag :/

Comment: Before you operate a machine connected to the Internet please learn the basics of the operating system. A badly maintained machine easily becomes hacked and then serves as spamboot, ddos bot or in some other bad way hurting others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

and nodejs worked again!

Answer (score 13):

As in @Quentin's answer, the name of the executable may be incorrect. In many cases, what got installed was `nodejs`, not `node`. The line below creates a [symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link) that points to `nodejs` from where your system looks when you type `node`. It is a work-around - an alternative to simply typing `nodejs`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node`

Answer (score 2):

The Debian package for NodeJS is called *nodejs* and installed the executable `/usr/bin/nodejs`.

`node` is the wrong program, it is for ham radio operations, and your install of it appears to be broken anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong happened during your node's installing.

And system environment variable shows the command "node" referes to /usr/sbin/node .

Try download node linux binaries from official. Rename and put it in /usr/sbin after extracting the source. Of course you can put it in another folder as long as you update the system environment variables.