# Create an alias for a file in Terminal

Tags: python, bash, macos

I want to create an alias for a file in macOS, but in the Terminal, not in the Finder (the file explorer).

My intent is to run a script and create file aliases for files in the current directory.

Comment: In case you mean a *"Finder alias"* https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=14923

Comment: What do you mean by "alias"?  In bash, alias has a specific meaning which does not seem to be related to your usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the heart of macOS is a UNIX-like operating system known as Darwin, which is based on several different UNIX variants (BSD,  NeXTSTEP, Mach). The Terminal application presents the user with a shell known as the `bash` shell (this is the default). In order to link one file to another in `bash`, you'd use `ln` and either create a soft link (also known as a symbolic link) or a hard link.

In contrast to a soft link, a hard link is tied to an element on the file system that has nothing to do with the original file's name (this element is known as an *inode*). The disadvantage of a soft link is that, if the original file that it is linked to is renamed, the process of renaming breaks the symbolic/soft link. However, soft links do have the advantage of being able to span file systems.[‡](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link)

To create a soft link, you'd use the `-s` flag:

`ln -s <original> <link>`

`<link>` is now a symbolic link to `<original>`.

To create a hard link, you'd simply use `ln` without the `-s` flag:

`ln <original> <link>`

A more concrete example:

```
[tmp]$ ls -al *.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chb chb 0 Jul 31 12:00 script.py
[tmp]$ ln -s script.py alias.py
[tmp]$ ls -al *.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chb chb 9 Jul 31 12:01 alias.py -> script.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chb chb 0 Jul 31 12:00 script.py
```

Comment: If this is what the OP is asking, the question belongs on [unix.se] rather than Stack Overflow, as nothing in this answer (or presumably the question) is "unique to software development". In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and therein the bullet point regarding questions which "are not about programming as defined in the help center".