# Python3 is now the default python on my Mac. How do I change that?

Tags: python, macos

I was having difficulties upgrading python3 which I downloaded from python.com. Anytime I try upgrading it, the new version doesn't show up on the terminal, so I remember going by what someone had posted on this platform about alias =... something I can't remember.

Now the problem is that, when I type python on my terminal, it shows the current version (3.10.4) of python while when I type python3, it shows the default version (3.8.8) on my terminal.

Can someone help me rectify this problem?[image]

Comment: i’ve kinda lived with it and i personally think it’s good to be explicit

Comment: I was okay with it until I started using django. I have django installed on my computer but anytime I run the server, it says i have no module named Django.

Answer (score 0):

What gets executed when you type a command in the [shell](https://zsh.sourceforge.io) is controlled by [the `PATH` environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) (unless the command is a [shell built-in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192373/what-are-shell-built-in-commands-in-linux). Some of the things you find along `PATH` are likely [symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314491/what-is-the-purpose-of-creating-a-symbolic-link-between-files).