# What is the "1" in this column "drwxr-xr-x 1 bash bash 4.0K Dec ..."

Tags: linux

I read that "1" is the number of hard links to the specific file, but what exactly are hard links?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a symbolic link and a hard link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link)

Comment: no of links a file has that number signifies that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In computing, a hard link is a directory entry that associates a name
> with a file on a file system. All directory-based file systems must
> have at least one hard link giving the original name for each file.
> The term “hard link” is usually only used in file systems that allow
> more than one hard link for the same file.

Comment: Though this provides an answer, its best to provide context and in particular, since this is a quote, its very important to provide a link to the original source (presumably Wikipedia in this case).