# Typescript compiler failing with soft symlinks when run in Windows

Tags: typescript, windows

I have symlinks in a typescript project that work just fine on macOS and linux. However, when running `tsc` in git-bash on Windows (not inside of WSL), `tsc` can't resolve the files.

Answer (score 0):

## edit

Hard links are not preserved as "links" in git, therefore using hard links does not work.

## Original answer

Solution: replace symlinks with hard links. Use `ln` instead of `ln -s`. This works on macOS, Linux, and Windows.

for more info about hard links vs sym links, see [What is the difference between a symbolic link and a hard link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185899)